# monacaでネットワーク一覧の取得方法

Tags: monaca

現在、monacaでアプリを開発したいと考えております。

アプリでスマホから接続できる無線LANの一覧を取得し、
ネットワークを選択後、パスワードを入力すると、
そのネットワークに繋げられる。
というのを作りたいと思っております。

monacaのドキュメントで、

https://docs.monaca.io/ja/reference/cordova_6.2/network-information/

ネットワーク情報を取得のプラグインはあったのですが、
こちらだと、今、スマホが繋いでいるのがwifiなのかとか、
そういう情報しか取れないように思えます。

windowsやmacで、wifiアイコンをクリックすると、
周囲に飛んでいるネットワーク一覧が表示されるのと同じイメージです。

こういった機能を実装すること自体可能なのでしょうか。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

カスタムプラグインを使いますが、
https://github.com/parsonsmatt/WifiWizard
を使うといけました。

Androidだけでしか確認してませんが、

javascript:

```
    function checkWifi() {
        WifiWizard.listNetworks( function(list) {
            alert( JSON.stringify( list ) );
        }, function(error) {
            alert( error );
        });
    }
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="checkWifi();">Check Wifi</button>
```

で、SSIDの一覧が取得できます。なぜか、SSIDの中にダブルクォートがついてました。